# Altered: How Might I Safely Handle Alteration of a List by Multiple Procedures?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, list, timer, flags

Iv'e pasted some code below to show some details of my concern.

**To explain**

I have a list(of type) for long/short term storage of objects.
User interaction will cause items to be added to or removed from the list.
Lack of user interaction will cause items to be removed after an event has fired for one of the items which prompts the removal.

I'm worried that the user will initiate some function that needs to work with the list or alter it just before one of the timer events is fired to alter the list. Specifically, I think the list will be altered by one routine while being accessed by another.

What I would like to do is to somehow force each routine wait for access to the list in a queue of sorts. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to accomplish this task.

Iv'e thought of using a flag to indicate that the list is busy. What I've determined is that I have no way to wait for the flag's status to change without blocking whatever routine is accessing the list. -Is there a trick to this?

Perhaps someone on here could help me with this issue -- maybe find some work around.

The few routines that I've included are just a small portion of the routines that will be trying to access the list.

```
Module EntryLocking
''' <summary>
''' Contains A list of locked entries
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private LockedEntries As New List(Of MyLockClass)
'-------------------------------------------------------concern----------
''' <summary>
''' Removes a locked entry from the LockedEntries list.
''' Accepts multiple class types for reference.
''' Will be called through user interaction and via timer, elapse events with the potential for simultaneous calls.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_Entry"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Sub RemoveLock(_Entry As Object)
    If GetType(Object).Equals(GetType(Entry)) Then
        Dim x As Entry = _Entry
        For Each e As MyLockClass In LockedEntries
            If e.PhisicalEntry.EntryID = x.EntryID And e.PhisicalEntry.Type = x.Type Then
                LockedEntries.Remove(e)
            End If
        Next
        'else if 'test for other types and handle the lock removal accordingly
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Defines an entry that's locked for editing. 
''' Contains a timer which elapses to warn the user that the lock is about to be released.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class MyLockClass

    Enum LockStatuses As Integer
        ''' <summary>
        ''' The entry is locked and the lock timer is counting down till time to submit a warning.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Idle = 0
        ''' <summary>
        ''' User has been warned. The next time the timer is elapsed, the entry should be removed.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        SubmittedTimerWarning = 1
        ''' <summary>
        ''' There are no time limits set for this entry. The timer is not counting and will not elapse.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Exempt = 2
    End Enum
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Contains information about the physical entry that's being locked.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Property PhisicalEntry As Entry


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Defines the current state of the locks timer. 
    ''' At timer elapsed, Idle status should trigger a warning to the user,
    ''' Warned status should prompt lock removal and exempt status should do nothing.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Property LockStatus As LockStatuses = LockStatuses.Exempt

    Private WithEvents LockTimer As New Timers.Timer

   
    Private Sub LockTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles LockTimer.Elapsed
        If Not Me.LockStatus = LockStatuses.Exempt Then
            LockTimer.Close()
            LockTimer = Nothing
            If Me.LockStatus = LockStatuses.Idle Then
                LockTimer = New Timers.Timer(30 * 1000)
                WarnUser_LockTimeExceeded()
                LockTimer.Start()
            Else

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' sends a warning to the user and offers a 30second chance for dismissal.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub WarnUser_LockTimeExceeded()
        'irrelevant code
    End Sub
End Class


End Module

Class Entry
    Property Type As String
    Property EntryID As Integer
End Class
```

All help is appreciated and I'm always open to creative criticism regarding my code and question posting.

**EDIT**

Ok, so it seems like I could use multi-threading to produce the results that I need. Please, someone advise on how to accomplish the following.

When a call is made to a sub routine to use or alter the list, it needs to be called on a separate thread. The separate thread can loop(forever) until a flag is raised saying that the list is available for use. The list and the flags will need to be on the top level thread but all sub threads need to access the flags and list. This is where I move into a new, unexplored territory. Please, does someone have a map?

**EDIT 2**

Going further, it seems that I should define some subroutines to call for altering my list. Inside the subroutines, I can set a synclock on any object that needs to be altered, make the changes and then remove the synclock. Anytime those specific routines are called, they can be called on a separate thread. I believe this would result in only one instance of access to the list at a time for the purposes of altering the list. Sound right?

Now, what about functions that don't need to alter the list but need to access it to pull specific, filtered information? If the last paragraph is the way to go, then I suppose that I need a method to prevent changes to the list while querying it for information. Any function I set up will need to send a return value so I don't believe that one at a time access will be possible via multi-threading.  Any pointers on this?

**Edit3**

I'm pretty sure that I have an answer for this. I need to test it a little and then I'll post.

**Edit 4**
So this project was abandoned some time ago when we decided that the database needed an update. I ended up indicating locked entries and database changes on a single table and poling for changes.
The changes are are processed after being raised to the level of the main thread.
Sorry i forgot about this thread.
Thanks for all input provided.

This is up and running successfully and without issue.
[image]

Comment: One thing, why not use a parameter of type Entry instead of an object in the `RemoveLock` method and have to do all those unnecessary checks?

Comment: @onefineDay The Idea behind this is that I will need to call the procedure in a variety of situations. There are many instances where the procedure making this call will have no need to work with a type of lockedEntry. Other situations include making the call with string as a parameter. Other situations will include removing all entries that belong to a certain user, in which case type RegisteredUser will be passed.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I suppose I've just grown accustom to handling objects. Some of the classes I've created take object as a parameter for new(). The Classes, representing entries in a database, Checks to see what kind of data row  it was given and then fills in the missing data for various fields. For instance. The entry might be a client or it might be a sample which belongs to a client. Either way, the class will return a value for the relative field. approx, 12 tables + other 70 row types that get translated to this single object which makes it easier to work with in the long run.